# C# hashing algorithm MD5(Sha1(pass))

Tags: c#, algorithm, hash, cryptography

So basically i got this algorithm:

MD5(SHA1(PASSWORD));

and i am trying to compute it in c#, however i am having no luck. Heres my current code:

```
string pass = txtPass.Text;
string sha1 = GetSha1(pass);
string md5 = CalculateMD5Hash(sha1);
textBox1.Text = md5;
```

However it doesnt output the proper data i know to be correct.

For example, if i were to convert "stackoverflow" to sha1 i would get:
fdfeb16f096983ada02db49d46a8154475d700ae

then if i were to md5 said sha1 i would get:
341fe8f2ac67f95f20d2d0b721d53847

However if i let my c# script do it, i get this:
381678D7800D83D014DB3DF1B704FE23

something isnt quite making sense here and im not sure what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MD5(SHA1("stackoverflow")); //341fe8f2ac67f95f20d2d0b721d53847

public String MD5(String input)
{
    System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
    Byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
    Byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

public String SHA1(String s)
{
    Byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
    var sha1 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create();
    Byte[] hashBytes = sha1.ComputeHash(bytes);
    return HexStringFromBytes(hashBytes);
}

public String HexStringFromBytes(Byte[] bytes)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(byte b in bytes)
    {
        var hex = b.ToString("x2");
        sb.Append(hex);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Looks to me that what you actually want is not the answer to `MD5(SHA1(UTF8(text)))` but to `HEX(MD5(UTF8(HEX(SHA1(UTF8(string)))))`. At least the hash over the hexadecimal construction is pretty weird. The output of a hash function is defined to be in binary, not hexadecimal characters.